# JS call function when calling object without method

Tags: javascript, oop, object

so I have an object **Obj** with some methods. If the object is called without any method I would like to run a specific method. Is that possible? If so how?

e.g.

```
function obj(variable){
    this.method = function(){};
    this.noMethod = function(){};
}
var test = new obj(variable);
```

Calling `console.log(test)` should now call noMethod on test. 
I hope you get what I mean.

The object has a nodelist if you call a method, it runs the method.
If you just call the object it should return the nodelist and possible alter it, depending on the argument.

Is there maybe a way to check if the object is called with a method? This way I could have an if-Statement to check and run my method if no other method is called.

Comment: Perhaps u should look into proxies http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:direct_proxies

Comment: Hi Lukas, what's the background to your problem? Are you looking for a way to see detail in the console?

Comment: I should have explained more, the object has a nodelist. I want to either run a method or return the nodelist.

Comment: So executing the console.log(test) would execute a method if no nodelist existed?

Comment: no, it would call a method if you call console.log(test('string').methodName()); if you call console.log(test('string')) it would just return the nodeList and possible edit it, depending on the argument.

Comment: Thanks Lukas, that makes it clearer. The console.log() is sending people down a different route suggesting toString() etc.

Comment: Okay, sorry for that.

Comment: No worries, it's a good question and it's got me thinking.

Answer (score 1):

have you looked into the arguments.length for javascript

```
function obj(variable, bool){
    if(bool)
     this.method = function(){}; 
    else
     this.noMethod = function(){};
}
var test = new obj(something, false);
```

calling `console.log(test)` should result in this.noMethod

Comment: your example is backwards, but valid.

Comment: I think this fails when doing new object('some value'); because it will not be 0.

Comment: @LukasOppermann if what I am understanding is correct then you should supply a optional bool. I understand this is a dumb way but it would get you what you need

`function(variable, bool){
   if(bool)
      this.method
   else
      this.noMethod
}`

Comment: `console.log(test, false)` logs `test` and `false` in the console, instead of calling `test.noMethod()`

Answer (score 1):

Note that the exact behavior you want is not possible (afaik), because

- You want to call `test.noMethod` without converting `test` into string, nor making it a function calling it. That means you need a getter.
- But if you add a getter to `test`, then `test.otherMethod` will call `test.noMethod` too!

Some alternatives:

- Use `.toString()` method:

  ```
  function Obj(variable){
      this.method = function(){};
      this.noMethod = function(){ alert('foo'); };
      this.toString = function(){ return this.noMethod(); }
  }
  var test = new Obj();
  test+''; // Calls test.noMethod, and returns test.noMethod()
  ```
- Use getters (1):

  ```
  function Obj(variable){
      this.method = function(){};
      this.noMethod = function(){ alert('foo'); };
  }
  var obj = {test: new Obj()}, tmp = obj.test;
  Object.defineProperty(obj, 'test', {
    get: function(){ return tmp.noMethod() }
  });
  obj.test; // Calls tmp.noMethod, and returns test.noMethod()
  obj.test.noMethod(); // Calls test.noMethod once and throws an error!
  ```
- Use getters (2):

  ```
  function Obj(variable){
      this.method = function(){};
      this.noMethod = function(){ alert('foo'); };
  }
  var obj = {test: new Obj()}, tmp = obj.test;
  Object.defineProperty(obj, 'test', {
    get: function(){ tmp.noMethod(); return tmp }
  });
  obj.test; // Calls tmp.noMethod, and returns tmp
  obj.test.noMethod(); // Calls test.noMethod twice!
  ```
- Use function:

  ```
  function Obj(variable){
      var f = function(){ return f.noMethod(); };
      f.method = function(){};
      f.noMethod = function(){ alert('foo'); };
      return f;
  }
  var test = new Obj();
  test(); // Calls test.noMethod, and returns test.noMethod()
  test instanceof Obj // false!
  ```

Answer (score 0):

This should call no method when used, and a method when called, if not then im not sure you can accomplish this without a function.

```
function Obj() {
  this.method = function(){};
  this.noMethod = function(){};
  return this.noMethod();
}
```

I originally said to use the arguments var but that still doesn't fit your request.

Comment: problem with this, as I initially posted similiar - is that in his obj, he'll call the method and call the no method.. since test.method() is also calling the obj without args.

Comment: using the "new" operator often refers to the "constructor design pattern"
To avoid misunderstanding of the code style / convention, please take a short look at the constructor pattern at
http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#constructorpatternjavascript

Comment: This would only work if I would never initialize obj with arguments, right? I need that too, adjusted above.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for this

```
function obj(){
    this.method = function(){};
    this.noMethod = function(){};
    this.toString = function() {return 'x'}
}
var test = new obj();
alert(test)
```

or this:

```
function obj(){
    this.method = function(){};
    this.noMethod = function(){};
}
obj.prototype.toString = function() {return 'x'}
var test = new obj();
alert(test)
```

See more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString

Comment: But this only works if I need it in a string context. If I do console.log(test) it would not call toString, correct? (Thats what happened when I tried it)

Comment: Correct. Console.log is a beast of it's own. AFAIK, it iterates project properties vs just calling toString.

Answer (score 0):

From your comments on the question, this doesn't quite solve what you are after, I'm not sure if that's really possible, as I think your trying to execute a function without calling a function - which is sort of possible with constructor ideas - but again I don't think you're after that.

But this sort of structure might give you some ideas for alternatives (though admittedly it's not really what you are after).

```
var test = function() {
    alert('hello');

    return {
        moo : function() {
            alert('moo');
        }
    }
};

var obj = test(); //hello

obj.moo(); //moo
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6Vpfa/

---

EDIT:

Maybe it does help, happy days :-)

Comment: Okay, it looks pretty much like it is exactly what I need, why are you saying it is not what I need?

Comment: Cool! That's lucky! The reason I thought otherwise is that test() is sort of acting like a constructor and should only be executed once, as it'll return a new "moo function" each time. But you may be able to twist this to suit your needs.

Comment: Darn I think it does actually not work. Because if you need to return the nodelist you run into trouble, it only works with alert, because it invokes itself.

Comment: Maybe a mixture of this an some magic "apply" stuff. But it may end up being counter intuitive when reading calling code as it's bending things quite a bit.